# Can't get sauce labs and travis CI to work

Tags: travis-ci, saucelabs

I'm trying to run a test with sauce labs + travis CI but no luck.

Here's where I think the issue is:
https://travis-ci.org/angulytics/angular-snitch/builds/50894194#L402

```
UnknownError: Sauce Labs Authentication Error.
You used username 'None' and access key 'None' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials.
```

However, I have added the keys to my travis settings page. Also, it looks like Travis is in fact exporting them

https://travis-ci.org/angulytics/angular-snitch/builds/50894194#L80

```
$ export SAUCE_USERNAME=[secure]
$ export SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=[secure]
```

So what's going on?

If it helps, you can check the rest of the protractor.conf here
https://github.com/angulytics/angular-snitch/blob/master/protractor.conf.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember where exactly I found the answer, but I had to remove the `seleniumAddress` config option for reasons I don't really understand.